# SSL certificates with Google API

Tags: php, curl

I encountered this quite some time ago with the MailChimp API, but downloading the latest version of `cacert.pem` and adding:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

to `php.ini` solved it. Is used it with different sites as well, but when connecting to the Google API, it fails. This is the code I use:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'.$query);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

And this is error I get:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: You just asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560596/ssl-certificate-problm-only-with-google-api

Comment: @EatPeanutButter: I know, but I edited that this was not the same case, but someone removed that part and now this is marked as duplicate as well. I wonder if they actually read the full question.